# how to make snort run with specified daq type on a target device

Tags: snort

Hi I want to make the **snort 2.9.4** run on the **mips-linux** based devices, so I cross compile the snort and all the supportive packages.

I use the option `--disable-static-daq`  when I configure snort because I dont want to utilize all the **daq** modes. What i need is just the **afpacket** mode.

When the cross compiling is OK, i move daq_afpacket.so, libsfbpf.so.0.0.1, libdaq.so.2.0.0, libdnet.1.0.1, libpcre.so.0.0.1, libpcap.so.1 to the target device's /usr/lib directory. And the binary snort is moved into target device's /bin directory.

Then i run the snort like this:

```
/bin/snort -vde --daq afpacket --daq-dir /usr/lib
```

The output shows:

Running in packet dump mode

```
    --== Initializing Snort ==--
```

Initializing Output Plugins!

/usr/lib/daq_afpacket.so: dlopen: File not found

segmentation fault

If  I run snort like this:

```
# /bin/snort -vde --daq afpacket
```

Running in packet dump mode

```
    == Initializing Snort =
```

Initializing Output Plugins!

ERROR: Can't find afpacket DAQ!

Fatal Error, Quitting..

Do you know what i miss here?

Answer (score 0):

let me answer it myself:

the daq_afpacket.so is depent on the libsfbpf.so.0, which is a symbol link to the so libsfbpf.so.0.0.1. Then i have to copy the libsfbpf.so.0.0.1 into /usr/lib and create the symobl link to it.

after that, snort can be started like:
/bin/snort -vde --daq afpacket --daq-dir /usr/lib --daq-var buffer_size_mb=2 -i eth0 &